# Wordpress 3.1 - How does one add sticky post capabilities to post types

Tags: custom-post-types, functions, pluggable, sticky-post

In wordpress 3.1 they finally added the option of allowing posts belonging to a custom post type to be marked as "sticky"... what I can't figure out though is how to enable this so the admin menu option shows up.

I was thinking it might have something to do with the "supports" argument when the post type is defined in the functions.php file however I can't find any references.

Any I on how I can get these sticky options to show up in the admin area?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As noted in the trac ticket, you need to add that UI element in yourself. If you're still looking for it, I made a plugin to add custom post type sticky support, available [**here**](http://www.superann.com/sticky-custom-post-types/).

Answer (score 2):

The feature was added then removed before the beta release.  It was decided that custom post types should not support the sticky argument.

See track [ticket #12702](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/12702)

Comment: errrgggg! that's ridiculous!

Comment: Subject to opinion, makes perfect sense to me.

Comment: That is silly, I'd like to know the logic behind NOT supporting stickiness for custom types - I guess we have to hack Wordpress to get this to work?

Comment: @JenUnderscore_ Read the track ticket for the logic.

Comment: how can it be illogical not include it! They should at least make it an option...