# how to make custom posts sticky?

Tags: custom-post-types, sticky-post

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Wordpress 3.1 - How does one add sticky post capabilities to post types](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/7130/wordpress-3-1-how-does-one-add-sticky-post-capabilities-to-post-types)

What I had was normal posts...until I realized that custom posts are what I should use for my purpose. But then I noticed that I don't have the option to make a custom post sticky from the admin panel. Is there a way to get that feature working?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

there was a big talk about that : http://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/12702

They ended deciding that a custom field will have to be used...

Comment: Thanks chriscatfr .....Will have to use custom fields and meta boxes then.